# CakePHP json response to multiple view files from one controller

Tags: cakephp

I need to pass a json response from my controller to multiple views. Is there a way I can implement this in cakephp??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CakePHP to do this, you just need JavaScript. There's ways to do this with JQuery, but here's a plain JS approach:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/controller/data.json', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(data);

    // Now you can update your view here.

  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    console.log(error)
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

If I misunderstood and you want to use different views with the same controller action (not necessarily JSON), you can do this in the controller action for your view:

```
$records = $this->Record->find('all');
$this->set('records', $records);

switch($variable){
    case "value1":
        $this->render("view1");
    break;
    case "value2":
        $this->render("view2");
    break;
    case "value3":
        $this->render("view3");
    break;
}
```

where view1 is `/View/Record/view1.ctp`, et cetera.